# if statement in search function linked list

Tags: c, search, linked-list, singly-linked-list, c-strings

I want to search in my linked list the string equal to x (parameter of function search) and return its value, but everytime the function return "doesn't exist" while idf in my list exists normaly.

I think the problem is the "if statement" doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it.

**my code**

```
typedef struct idf One;
struct idf {
    char *idf;
    int value;
    One *next;
};

typedef struct List_symb {
    One *head;
} List ;

int search(List T, char *x){
    One *p = T.head;
    while(p->next != NULL){
        if(p->idf == x){
            return p->value;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("doesn't exist\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You need to use `strcmp`.

Comment: you mean I use : if(strcmp(p->idf) == x)? @kiranBiradar

Comment: @Jo101 strcmp has two parameters

Comment: and it looks like you are never examining the last node of your list.

Comment: @Jo101 No, `if (strcmp(p->idf,x) == 0)`

Comment: To include the last node of the list in the search, replace `while(p->next != NULL)` with `while(p != NULL)`.

Comment: The test `p->idf == x` is only comparing the pointer values, which probably isn't what you want.  To see of the strings they point to are equal, use `strcmp(p->idf, x) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare pointed strings not the pointers themselves.

Moreover the function has undefined behavior if it is called for an empty list.

The function definition can look the following way

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int search( List *T, const char *s, int *value )
{
    One *p = T->head;

    while ( p != NULL && strcmp( p->idf, s ) != 0 ) p = p->next;

    int success = p != NULL;

    if ( success ) *value = p->value;

    return success; 
}
```

The function can be called like

```
List list = { NULL };
int value;

//...

if ( search( &list, "Hello", &value ) )
{
    printf( "The found value is %d\n", value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are quite tricky. Strings in C are just an array. Just like an array of `int` with one small but significant difference: **they must end with `'\0'`**.

Let's look at this part of your code:

```
...
if(p->idf == x){
    return p->value;
}
...
```

According to your code, the `idf` is an array of `char`. More precisely speaking it is a pointer to the first element of the array (this is how arrays work in C). What about `x`? It is the same type - pointer to the first element of a **different** array.

So what the `p->idf == x` does is compare addresses of arrays. If you want to compare to strings in C, you have two function to do that: `strcmp` and `strncmp`.

The first one iterates through arrays and compare corresponding values until it reaches `\0` (the end of string character). The second has one extra argument which tells the function how many comparisons it has to perform.

It all can be a little bit confusing at the start, but the idea of pointers is a very powerful feature, and it is straight forward when you get used to it.

If you would like to know about strings in C you should have a look [here](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html).